# I am trying to calculate trending posts on Facebook - would DynamoDB be the best or even fit for purpose?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database

I am currently pushing data into AWS DynamoDB and ultimately want to do some analysis with it.

What I really want to do is perhaps scrape Facebook's API and then store posts,likes, shares etc using possibly setting the primary key with the post's post_id (i.e. https://www.facebook.com/**1110933312276344**)

Then perhaps the harder part is have some sort of calculation to see what's trending. The calculation/analysis of course would be automated.

I can do the download, storage part easy but am unsure about the calculation- Would DynamoDB be the best?

Ideally, what I would like to do is download data at the post level from Facebook's Graph API and then if the post gets over a certain number of shares in under a certain time period, it would be marked as a 'trending' article. The end result would be an API endpoint that would list all the trending articles.

The end result, would be perhaps an API-endpoint JSON of all the trending articles.

Or shall I be looking at other solutions? Maybe MongDB?

Comment: This is a request for software options, and is very opinion based, thus not on-topic for Stack Overflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I can understand where you are coming from, however it would be good to know if even DynamoDB is able to do such calculations or that it's just not designed for something like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: sure, you'll store data at post-id level. but that doesn't tell us how you'll use it to find trending posts. what does 'trending' exactly mean? folks can answer better if you provide more clarity

Comment: @ketan What I would like to do is download data at the post level from Facebook's Graph API and then if the post gets over a certain number of shares in under a certain time period, it would be marked as a 'trending' article. 

The end result would be an API endpoint that would list all the trending articles.

Answer (score -1):

To cut right to the chase, I personally would not use Dynamo in your case, particularly if you are a small site who could otherwise be adequately serviced by a SQL store.

[I've written an implementation of Dynamo paper](https://github.com/zv/Artifact) as well as using Amazon's canonical offering and so I stress the paradigm rather than the pragmatics here.

The benefits of Dynamo or a dynamo-like offering is *very* substantial cost that it sounds like you won't be able to benefit from. Ensuring a consistent read or write for this sort of application isn't a profitable use of your time. On the other hand, ratcheting down your N,R and W to leaves you with a low-power memcache instance.

There are dozens, perhaps hundreds of hash-keyed data stores available and today traditional relational databases increasingly offer these sorts of interfaces as well. If you foresee **any** future back-end calculations or filtering of results -- save yourself the application logic and let a relational SQL database handle it for you.

You may have some marketing literature from Amazon in front of you right now, some of which suggests that switching to Dynamo will give you peace of mind or more nebulous gains in technical sophistication. Amazon (as of early 2015) does not publish details of their backing storage, but based on the performance of Dynamo system historically, I have little reason to believe that it is anything but spinning-disks -- if you run a dynamo-inspired database yourself, the problem of storage libraries will emerge ten-fold.